# How to change the print options in POS?

Tags: printing, point-of-sale

I would like to use POS with my custom printer. So the form of the bill /invoice is formated for a small printer. I would like to print on normal A4 paper. how can I edit the settings of the outgoing printing in POS?

Comment: Not sure that this question is suited to this forum, which is really about programming. Do you have access to the source code of the POS?

Answer (score 0):

Usually POS requires COM device to print. You should read the printer programming manual to see how to call the command. If USB, you should use the vendor's USB library.